# I have had the same audit 4 times now

Tags: discussion, review-audits

I just got the following review for the forth time:

> MAKE US MODS OR WE WON'T STOP!
>
> WE ARE STILL NO SURRENDERED BY YOU, WE WILL NEVER GIVE UP.
>
> The Indian Team Hackers
>
> ldkcfjih3gw78hNBYUg

After audit completed:

[image]

Could there be something that means you don't get the same audit twice, including across multiple queues?

Comment: I was around on one of their spamming sprees. Believe me, they posted a rather large number of posts with different users (and different IPs, judging from the gravatar). Plenty of fodder for the audit system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might not be the *same* audit, technically.

We got a large number of similar or identical spam/troll posts like that one. You're probably getting different ones in each audit, that look similar.

I've gotten a number of audits with that spam as well.